# named Transfer failed

Tags: bind, named

dig @111.1111.111.111 domain.ru. axfr

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.2 <<>> @95.85.36.112 domain.ru. axfr
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
; Transfer failed.

Google already searched all.
I can not understand what's wrong?

Му named.conf options

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 {
                0.0.0.0;
                };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query { any; };
        recursion no;
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;
        allow-transfer {111.1111.111.111;};
```

Не могу понять что произходит?
Что я делаю не так ?

I can not understand that occured?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[`allow-transfer`](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/xfer.html#allow-transfer) is the directive allow a group of hosts to be able to transfer *from* a server.  In your case, `111.1111.111.111` (which, by the way, is not a valid ip address because the second quad has too many `1`s).

Your dig command (`dig @111.1111.111.111 domain.ru. axfr`) is asking to transfer *from* server at ip `111.1111.111.111` (once again not a valid ip).

So, I think you need to update the `allow-transfer` directive to include whatever computer you are running `dig` from.